# How to start an application within a terminal in one command

Tags: scripting, gnome-terminal, xterm

I need to start an application automatically within a terminal like xterm or gnome-terminal in one command line. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. That is the perfect and total answer to the question as you composed it. (Ask a vague question, and get the appropriate answer. I'm not meaning to be rude, just pointing out that people can't read your mind and know what you want, you need to actually make the effort of typing words in intelligible paragraphs, providing details, and examples when possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm, yes. I'm leaving out the "without user intervention" bit here, because I don't know what that means in this context.

With `xterm`:

```
xterm -e somecommand
```

The terminal will exit as soon as `somecommand` exits.  If that's not wanted, you may explicitly start an interactive shell as well:

```
xterm -e sh -c 'somecommand; bash'
```

See the `xterm` manual (`man xterm`).

I'm sure that `gnome-terminal` can do the same (see *its* manual).

Comment: You answered my question very well. I missed the '-e' option while checking the manpage of 'xterm'.